# Как называется виджет с вкладками?

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как сделать 2 такие кнопки.

Это  TabLayout или что? Меня больше всего смущает белая полоска над активной кнопкой

Comment: это не Toolbar, а [TabHost](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/tabhost-tabwidget.php) . Полоска, видимо, все же ПОД "кнопкой".

Comment: Вообщем я добавил ToolBar вместе с TabLayout нормально работает, также как на картинке

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На картинке у Вас изображен `TabLayout` - [Здесь](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/) находится хороший пример полностью реализованный и интуитивно понятный с объяснениями и комментариями и самое главное сделан в стиле `material design` как у Вас в примере.

*P.S. Там очень много нужного и смысла нет в показе одного кусочка кода, поэтому прошу не удалять данный ответ:)*

Comment: TabHost устарел и его теперь заменяет TabLayout)

Comment: @ЮрийСпб спасибо что сказали) исправил ответ, В ссылке реализован через TabLayout. Я вообще обычно использую navigtionview, с Tabhost работал давным давно и поэтому его вспомнил.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб какой вы категоричный. `ListView` устарел, `TabHost` устарел, в то время, как в API ни тот ни другой не объявлен Deprecated и вместо них не рекомендуются ни `RecyclerView` ни `TabLayout `- каждому виджету свое применение. `ListView` гораздо более уместен в простых списках, с одной\двумя строчками текста, вроде диалогового окна с пунктами, по типу спиннера. `TabHost` не использует адаптер и для простых "страничек" тоже гораздо более уместен. Всему свое место и не надо делать сложнее там, где можно проще.